# How to direct build output for OpenSSL on OS X

Tags: macos, makefile, openssl

I am building OpenSSL on OS X. I would like to direct the built libraries (`libcrypto.a`, `libssl.a` etc) to a directory of my choice. Currently they are put in the current working directory.

How do I do achieve that?

This is what I'm doing. I thought specifying the directory for the `openssldir`option might do it but it doesn't.

```
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --openssldir=my-dir
make
```

Comment: I think you will want to use the `--prefix` option, in addition to `--openssldir`.  For my local OpenSSL builds on OSX, I use: `CC=gcc ./Configure darwin64-x64_64-cc --prefix=/path/to/my/dir --openssldir=/path/to/my/dir`.  Note that the `CC=gcc` environment variable is useful for the `make depend` step that newer OpenSSL builds may require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to direct the built libraries (libcrypto.a, libssl.a etc) to a directory of my choice. Currently they are put in the current working directory.

OpenSSL 1.1.0 can build in-tree or out-of-tree. OpenSSL 1.0.2 builds in-tree. In both cases all the artifacts are in the OpenSSL root directory. Its effectively hard coded into the scripts (there's two or three of them that interact).

You put them in the directory of your choice by following the build with a `make install`. If you only care about the libraries (libcrypto.a, libssl.a) then manually `cp` them.

If needed you can locate the artifacts with:

```
find . -name 'libssl*'
find . -name 'libcrypto*'
find . -name '*\.o'
```

There's also some rules about when to use `--prefix=XXX` and when to use `--openssldir=XXX`. It depends on both the OpenSSL version number, and the make recipe like `make install` or `make install_sw`. For the details, see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: `find . -name './libssl*'` doesn't list anything. However, `find . -name 'libssl*'` lists `./libssl.a` and `./libssl.pc`. Same for `libcrypto`.

Comment: @ksl - My bad... I'm not sure why I put them there. I run those commands often and know better...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to re-direct OpenSSL output to your specific directory, then you need to execute configure script like this:

```
$ ./configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/Users/username/mydir --openssldir=/Users/username/mydir/ssl
```

where "username" is your user name. In this example the output will be performed into "~/mydir" directory. Here:

```
--prefix option sets the output directory
--openssldir option sets the ssl settings directory
```